# Anidación en React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6, redux

Hola no comprendo por que no funciona una anidacion anteriormente ya la habia hecho pero hoy no.
no lee las this.props.children el Adm pero las otras como home de Adm si.

Routes

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Miss} from 'react-router-dom'
import ferreteriasLogin from './containers/ferreteria/login/Login.jsx'
import adminLogin from './containers/admin/login/Login.jsx'
import home from './containers/home/home.jsx'
import Auth from './modules/Auth'
import indexAdmin from './containers/admin/index/index.jsx'
import noMatch from './componets/404/index.jsx'
import AdminCuentas from './containers/admin/administracion/cuentas/index.jsx'
import Adm from './containers/admin/administracion/adm.jsx'
const Main = () => (

    <Switch>
      <Route path ='/' exact component={Indexs()}/>
      <Route path='/ferreterias' component={ferreteriasLogin}/>
      <Route path='/admins' component={adminLogin}/>

      <Route path='/adm' component={Adm} />
      <Route path='/adm/cuentas' component={AdminCuentas} />

      <Route component={noMatch} />
    </Switch>

)

const Indexs = () =>{
    if(Auth.isUserAuthenticated()){
      if(Auth.isUserAuthenticated() === 'ADMIN' )
        return (indexAdmin)
    }else{
      return (home)
    }
}
export default Main;
```

Adm

```js
import React from 'react';
import Menu from '../home/home.jsx'
import Auth from '../../../modules/Auth'

class Adm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

  }

  // componentWillMount() {
  //   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //   xhr.open('get', '/admin');
  //   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  //   // set the authorization HTTP header
  //   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `bearer ${localStorage.getItem('admin')}`);
  //   xhr.responseType = 'json';
  //   xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
  //     if (xhr.status === 200) {
  //
  //     }else{
  //       if(xhr.status === 401){
  //         Auth.desauthenticateUser()
  //         this.props.history.push('/')
  //       }
  //     }
  //   });
  //   xhr.send();
  // }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Menu children={this.props.children}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Adm;
```

Cuentas

```js
import React from 'react';
import CuentasCompo from '../../../../componets/admin/administracion/cuentas/index.jsx'

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

  }

  render() {
    return (<CuentasCompo
             />);
  }

}

export default Login;
```

Home

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux"

//componets
import Menu from '../../../componets/admin/home/home.jsx'
import Auth from '../../../modules/Auth'


//actions
import {HANDLE_TAP_HOME} from './actions'

//store
import store from '../../../redux/store'


@connect((store)=>{
  return{
    open:store.homeHome.open
  }
})

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.handleTap = this.handleTap.bind(this);
  }


  handleTap(){
    store.dispatch(HANDLE_TAP_HOME())
  }


  render() {
    return (<Menu
            handleTap={this.handleTap}
            open={this.props.open}
            children={this.props.children}
             />);
  }

}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Veo que haz publicado varias preguntas sobre React. Deberías preguntar en Stackoverflow en inglés, aquí no te van a responder o solucionar dudas... sobre esta pregunta, el API de la versión 4 cambia mucho así que te sugeriría leer la documentación, igual te dejo el link a una pregunta similar: [React Router v4 nested routes props.children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180088/react-router-v4-nested-routes-props-children)

Comment: @Gerardo       Okey Gracias Ya Solucione Mi problema :!

Comment: Aquí sí hay gente que sabe sobre React, React Router y Redux, @Gerardo, yo soy una de ellas y con gusto ayudaré. No recomiendes ir a otro sitio, apoya este.

Comment: Vale, si lo solucionaste, publica la solución o elimina tu pregunta si así lo consideras.

Comment: PD: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: En un momento público el código Completo pues la forma de la nueva versión cambia y no se pasa así las props a los componentes si no dentro de los componentes se introduce un Swich con Route de las rutas que él tendrá por lo tanto las hijas podrán acceder a las props de las del padre.

Comment: @valeale Recomiendo que publiques tu respuesta, es perfectamente valido en las reglas del sitio y asi ayudaras a futuros usuarios con el mismo problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey después de investigar sobre la nueva versión de react-Router  me dice en la documentación que dentro de los componentes que se anidaran las rutas o sera sus hijos seria así.

```js
import React from 'react';


import Cuentas from '../../../../containers/admin/administracion/cuentas/Header.jsx'
import Routes from '../../../../containers/admin/home/Header.jsx'
import Settings from '../../../../containers/admin/config/settings/Header.jsx'

import noMatch from '../../404/404.jsx'

import { Switch, Route, Miss} from 'react-router-dom'

const CardExampleExpandable = () => (
  <div>
  <Switch>

    <Route exact path='/' component={Routes} />
    <Route path='/adm/cuentas' component={Cuentas} />
    <Route path='/adm/settings' component={Settings} />
    <Route component={noMatch} />
  </Switch>
  </div>

)

export default CardExampleExpandable;
```

Y en Routes.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Miss} from 'react-router-dom'

import ferreteriasLogin from './containers/ferreteria/login/Index.jsx'
import adminLogin from './containers/admin/login/Index.jsx'
import home from './containers/home/Index.jsx'

import Auth from './modules/Auth'

import indexAdmin from './containers/admin/Base/Index.jsx'
import noMatch from './componets/404/index.jsx'

const Main = () => (

    <Switch>
      <Route path ='/' exact component=home}/>
      <Route path='/ferreterias' component={ferreteriasLogin}/>
      <Route path='/admins' component={adminLogin}/>

      <Route path='/adm' component={indexAdmin} />
      <Route component={noMatch} />
    </Switch>

)


}
export default Main;
```

los componentes a los que deseas que sean los padres de ciertas rutas agregarles las rutas para que dentro de ellos las renderizen. Esto a mi me funcionó. Espero les funcione!

Comment: Por si aún no lo sabes, puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No te lo va aceptar como propiedad debes encerarlo con tu componente **Menú**.

algo a si:

**opción 1**

```
<Menu
  {this.props.children}
/>
```

**opción 2**

```
<Menu>
   {this.props.children}
</Menu>
```

Comment: esto es si lo quieres mostrar en el menú o bien puedes hacerlo en tu componente Menú y donde quieras mostrarlo es donde debes de poner los hijos